# Does django cache related tables when they are used in filter()

Tags: python, django, django-models

For instance:

```
e = Entries.objects.filter(blog__name='Something')
```

Does this cache `blog` as well or should I still add `select_related('blog')` to this.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33230540/django-select-related-when-to-use-it#33230991

Comment: Well, when you run that code and then examine the attributes of e, do you see attributes from blog or just entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `filter(blog__name='Something')` means that Django will do a join when it fetches the queryset. However if you want to access the related blogs you still have to use `select_related`.

You might find django-debug-toolbar useful so that you can check the queries yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You will see attributes of everything **blog** and anything farther down as well. Django automagically takes care of it all. But it will do additional queries internally as needed to get blog (beyond **blog_id**) and anything else. Use **select_related** to get anything you know you will use. If **select_related** doesn't work then most of the time **prefetch_related** will work instead. The difference is that **prefetch_related** does an extra query for each table. That is still better than letting Django do everything automagically if the query includes more than one record of the main table - i.e., 1 + 1 instead of 1 + n.

I suspect part of the confusion is about **filter()**. **filter** and **exclude** and other ways of getting anything less than **all()** will reference the other tables in the **WHERE** part of the query but Django doesn't retrieve fields from those tables unless/until you access them, unless you use **select_related** or **prefetch_related**.