# Convert join SQL query into django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am new to django and trying out stuff with it.

How do I display selected fields from the joined table.
For example:

I have two models, X and Y. I am merging these two models based on the foreign key of model Y.

```
class X(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)


class Y(models.Model):
    owner_user = models.ForeignKey(X, models.DO_NOTHING, 
    db_column='id')
    detail = models.CharField()
```

How do I write this query as a django code?

**SELECT name, id, Body_details
FROM X, Y
WHERE X.id = Y.OwnerUserId;**

Comment: Can you please share the actual models?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/

Comment: I have added the model files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

```
a = Y.objects.select_related('OwnerUserId').all()

for object in a:
    print(object.OwneruserId.name, object.OwneruserId.id, object.body)
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the response. But is there a way to return it as a HttpResponse in Json format instead of using print statement. I am stuck with that part.

Comment: @lazycoderboi, checkout : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2428119/5588787

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `select_related` here.

> result = Y.objects.select_related('owner_use')

All the work behind joining will automatically be done by this ORM using `select_related`. You can see previously asked questions similar to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33231194/9246099).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **[`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)** of the `ForeignKey` field, which is `y_set` by default, to access the reverse relationship of model :

```
some_id = 1
instance = X.objects.get(id=some_id)
instance.y_set.all()
```