# Django fetch data from table that refers the given table as foreign key

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have seen several examples of using select_related to query foriegn key related data in queryset. Including this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33230540/django-select-related-when-to-use-it). But I want to do it in reverse way as explained below.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name   = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)

class Author(models.Model):
    name   = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I have seen queryset to fetch the data while querying the Book because Author is specified in books.Like this
`books = Book.objects.all().select_related("author")`
But I need to query Author and then get all the books related with it.Is there any way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `related_name` in the FK definition:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name="books")
```

An then, from `Author` you can:

```
Author.objects.all().prefetch_related("books")
```

Check [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) for more info.

Comment: that works but I only get the id field when I send a response. all the other fields are not shown in the response

Comment: Also select_related wasnt working for me.Prefetch related did.

Comment: You are right, my bad. When you are getting a set of objects you use `prefetch_related`. Updated the answer